# R Plotly and shiny : Cstack error, but no error in viewer pane

Tags: r, shiny, plotly, boxplot, rstudio-server

I'm trying to plot a not that large `data.frame` with 20 columns and 10000 rows with `plot_ly` inside a shiny-Application. I get the error that the Cstack usage is exceeded:

```
Error : C stack usage  11550256 is too close to the limit

Cstack_info()
  size    current  direction eval_depth 
7969177      15056          1          2
```

However, the function works properly from the Rstudio source pane and is rendered in the viewer pane. 
Can anyone explain what is going on and give advice on how to solve this error ?

Thanks in advance !

Here minimal working and non working examples:

```
library(shiny)
library(plotly)
library(reshape2)
library(viridis)

## create data.frame

m <- matrix(rnorm(200000, 100, 10), ncol = 20)
dim(m)
rownames(m) <- paste0("A", "_", 1:nrow(m))
colnames(m) <- paste0("Sample", "_", 1:ncol(m))

## Plotting in the viewer pane -> works fine

y <- melt(m)
y <- group_by(y, Var2)

p <-
  plot_ly(
    y,
    x = ~ Var2,
    y = ~ value,
    color = ~ Var2,
    type = "box",
    showlegend = F,
    colors = viridis(ncol(m))
  )

print(p)


## Not working in shiny

ui <- fluidPage(plotlyOutput("plot"))

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$plot <- renderPlotly({
    y <- melt(m)
    y <- group_by(y, Var2)

    p <-
      plot_ly(
        y,
        x = ~ Var2,
        y = ~ value,
        color = ~ Var2,
        type = "box",
        showlegend = F,
        colors = viridis(ncol(m))
      )

    print(p)
  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: I can't reproduce on windows 7 / R 3.3.2 with latest CRAN version of shiny and plotly

Comment: I'm working on Rstudio-server with R 3.2.3 on a UbuntuMate 16.04 Workingstation.

Comment: I see same problem, running R 3.4.1, Shiny 1.2.0, Plotly 4.8.0. I have a similar issue using a different set of data and are looking for a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this question has not received attention for quite some time and does not appear to be resolved. I can reproduce with the above example and find that if the observations are less than 173,300 it will work, but above that number of observations I get the same "Error: C stack usage xxx is too close to the limit".
Perhaps the OP was able to resolve? If so please post an update. Thanks

```
> runApp('ShinyApps/test')

Listening on http://127.0.0.1:3833
SEND {"config": 
{"workerId":"","sessionId":"252a5c03dce4dc01503a7941b18395e4","user":null}}
RECV {"method":"init","data": {".clientdata_output_plot_width":930,".clientdata_output_plot_height":400,".clientdata_output_plot_hidden":false,".clientdata_pixelratio":1,".clientdata_url_protocol":"http:",".clientdata_url_hostname":"ilscha03-hpen-01.uscc.com",".clientdata_url_port":"8787",".clientdata_url_pathname":"/p/3833/",".clientdata_url_search":"",".clientdata_url_hash_initial":"",".clientdata_url_hash":"",".clientdata_singletons":"",".clientdata_allowDataUriScheme":true}}
SEND {"busy":"busy"}
SEND {"recalculating":{"name":"plot","status":"recalculating"}}
SEND {"recalculating":{"name":"plot","status":"recalculated"}}
SEND {"busy":"idle"}
Error: C stack usage  9961999 is too close to the limit

> sessionInfo()
R version 3.4.1 (2017-06-30)
Platform: x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.10 (Santiago)

Matrix products: default
BLAS: /usr/lib64/R/lib/libRblas.so
LAPACK: /usr/lib64/R/lib/libRlapack.so

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C               LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8        
LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8     LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8   
 [6] LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8    LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                  
LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C            
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] viridis_0.5.1        viridisLite_0.3.0    reshape2_1.4.3       bindrcpp_0.2.2       plotly_4.8.0         DT_0.5.1             lubridate_1.6.0     
 [8] DBI_1.0.0            RODBC_1.3-15         sparklyr_0.9.4       dplyr_0.7.8          purrr_0.2.5          readr_1.2.1          tidyr_0.8.2         
[15] tibble_1.4.2         ggplot2_3.1.0        tidyverse_1.1.1      stringr_1.3.1        shinydashboard_0.7.1 shinyjs_1.0          shiny_1.2.0         

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_1.0.0        lattice_0.20-38   forge_0.1.0       assertthat_0.2.0  rprojroot_1.3-2   digest_0.6.18     mime_0.6          R6_2.3.0         
 [9] cellranger_1.1.0  plyr_1.8.4        backports_1.1.2   httr_1.3.1        pillar_1.3.0      rlang_0.3.0.1     lazyeval_0.2.1    readxl_1.1.0     
[17] rstudioapi_0.8    data.table_1.11.8 config_0.3        r2d3_0.2.2        htmlwidgets_1.3   munsell_0.5.0     broom_0.5.1       compiler_3.4.1   
[25] httpuv_1.4.5      modelr_0.1.2      pkgconfig_2.0.2   base64enc_0.1-3   htmltools_0.3.6   openssl_1.1       tidyselect_0.2.5  gridExtra_2.3    
[33] crayon_1.3.4      dbplyr_1.2.2      withr_2.1.2.9000  later_0.7.5       grid_3.4.1        nlme_3.1-137      jsonlite_1.5      xtable_1.8-3     
[41] gtable_0.2.0      magrittr_1.5      scales_1.0.0      stringi_1.2.4     promises_1.0.1    xml2_1.2.0        generics_0.0.2    tools_3.4.1      
[49] forcats_0.3.0     glue_1.3.0        crosstalk_1.0.0   hms_0.4.2         parallel_3.4.1    rsconnect_0.8.12  yaml_2.2.0        colorspace_1.3-2 
[57] rvest_0.3.2       bindr_0.1.1       haven_2.0.0      
>
```

Comment: Hi @JeffKraus, it seems, that this is a kind of bug. Using R 3.4.4, shiny 1.2.0, plotly 4.8.0, reshape2 1.4.3 and viridis 0.5.1 the problem does not longer exists. I removed `print(p)` from shiny code, since it shows the plot in the viewer pane. Maybe this is helpful to you.